# How to traverse a table in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in Oracle (12c) which I need to retrieve data.
The table is called ACCOUNT_ANALYSIS_FY16.  This table holds a 3 level hierarchy of businesses.  The position in this hierarchy is designated by the column DUNS_LEVEL, whose value is DUNS (meaning the lowest level of a business), IMMEDIATE (meaning a level 2, aka Parent of DUNS level) or ULTIMATE, (meaning level 3, or Parent of IMMEDIATE).

```
Applicable columns are:
NN_NAME - Account Name
DUNS_LEVEL
DUNS
ULTIMATE_PARENT_DUNS
IMMEDIATE_PARENT_DUNS
```

The requirement... for a given account name (and there may be multiple occurrences for the same account name due to different locations), I need to see everything about that account (aka SELECT *), AS WELL AS everything about the Immediate Parent and the Ultimate Parent of the given account.

I have written this in SQL, but it involves 5 SELECT statements.  I know there has to be a more elegant and simple way to do this.  Note that the end result is to place this in an anonymous PL/SQL block, so it is acceptable to write a PL/SQL block if that is a better solution.

Here is the straight SQL that I have which works...

```
Select *from ACCOUNT_ANALYSIS_FY16 where NN_NAME = 'XYZ GROUP'
union
Select * from ACCOUNT_ANALYSIS_FY16 where DUNS in (Select IMMEDIATE_PARENT_DUNS from ACCOUNT_ANALYSIS_FY16 where NN_NAME = 'XYZ GROUP')
union
Select * from ACCOUNT_ANALYSIS_FY16 where DUNS in (Select ULTIMATE_PARENT_DUNS from ACCOUNT_ANALYSIS_FY16 where NN_NAME = 'XYZ GROUP')
```

Thanks

Comment: could you do it as a hierarchical query not real sure the structure of your data so you might have to play around with it but something like                                                                                                                          select a.*,  level, sys_connect_by_path(nm_name,'/') "Path"
from account_analysis_fy16 a
start with ultimate_parent_duns is null and nm_name = 'XYZ Group'
connect by prior immediate_parent_duns = ultimate_parent_duns or prior  duns = immediate_parent_duns;

Comment: Frankly I like the original SQL. It's clear what it's doing and it's easy to read. Unless there's a performance issue I see no reason to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM ACCOUNT_ANALYSIS_FY16 t
WHERE NN_NAME = 'XYZ GROUP'
  OR EXISTS (
     SELECT NULL 
     from ACCOUNT_ANALYSIS_FY16 t1
     WHERE t.DUNS IN ( t1.ULTIMATE_PARENT_DUNS, t1.IMMEDIATE_PARENT_DUNS )
       AND t1.NN_NAME = 'XYZ GROUP'
  )
```

Comment: Once I added the appropriate indexes, this did exactly what I needed.